# Updating day of the week on first form load?

Tags: c#, triggers

Im wondering will this part of code work, because I don't want 2 triggers to trigger if its Saturday or Sunday:

```
    private void Pocetna_forma_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SetUpTimer(new TimeSpan(20, 10, 00));


        string proba =Convert.ToString( DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
        if(proba!="Sunday" || proba != "Saturday")
        {
            Timer_bolovanje(new TimeSpan(20, 00, 00));
            Timer_godisnji(new TimeSpan(20, 05, 00));
        }
     ...
     }
```

The thing is, my form is loaded on main server and the program is never shut down and the trigger called "SetUpTimer" works perfectly, Im just curious before I can test it, will this if statement work, or better said, will string "proba" update itself every time it hits midnight and did I place the triggers in the right spot inside the code?

Comment: What do the Timer_bolovanje and Timer_godisnji functions do?

Comment: If the form is only loaded once, then those other 2 timers will only be /configured/ on a Saturday or Sunday.   If you ran the code on a Monday (and let it run for a week), those 2 other timers would NOT be fired.

Comment: @Neil Timer_godisnji updates one column in database and raises value by 1, same thing for Timer_godisnji but this one lowers the value by 1, basically I start a program, and rearly turn it off on the server, when I turn it off its because I do some updates in code, then i start it again....I need a constant way for those triggers to run, coz bolovanje means sick day, and godisnji means vacation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about always kicking off the timers once a day, but within the timer tick, check if it is Saturday or Sunday?

Something like :

```
private void Pocetna_forma_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SetUpTimer(new TimeSpan(20, 10, 00));
    Timer_bolovanje(new TimeSpan(20, 00, 00));
    Timer_godisnji(new TimeSpan(20, 05, 00));
}

void InTimerBolovanje_Tick()
{
    if(dow == DayOfWeek.Sunday || dow == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        DoBolovanje_Thing()
    }
}
void InTimerGodisnji_Tick()
{
    if(dow == DayOfWeek.Sunday || dow == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        Godisnji_Thing()
    }
}
```

Comment: I really dont care if he even starts 7 times a day, as long as it it constant and working, thanks Neil, I'll give it a shot =)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to your question but, I think it is dangerous to take a enum (DayOfWeek) and convert it to a string to compare the day name.  From your variables I assume you are Croatian, therefore possibly the day of week might be converted into a different string depending on the language the OS is running in?  Anyway, I would do:

```
var dow = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
if(dow != DayOfWeek.Sunday || dow != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
{
    Timer_bolovanje(new TimeSpan(20, 00, 00));
    Timer_godisnji(new TimeSpan(20, 05, 00));
}
```

Comment: I'll do that, worth of trying, and yea I am Croatian haha, btw do you think that just by putting the trigger inside form_load event it will automaticly update itself?